# how to change basic class values C++

Tags: c++, class

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class CCounter
{

private:
int mAmount; // stores the current count value

public:
    void Set( int number ); // set count to the value of number
    int  Get();         // get the current value of amount
    int  Top();         // gets top
    void Increment();   // increment count by 1
    void Decrement();   // decrement by 1
};


void CCounter::Set( int number )
{
    mAmount = number;
}

int CCounter::Get()
{
    return mAmount;
}

int CCounter::Top()
{
    int topp = mAmount;
    mAmount = 0;

    return topp;
}

void CCounter::Increment()
{
    mAmount+=4;
}

void CCounter::Decrement()
{
    mAmount-=3;   
}

int main(){

    CCounter* myCount = new CCounter;

    myCount->Set( 6 );
    myCount->Increment();

    int tmp = myCount->Get();
    cout << tmp << endl;



    delete ( myCount );
    system("pause");
}
```

Hi guys. i have a basic counter class. I need a help implementing my `Top()` function in `main()` im trying to set the value of `mAMount` to `topp` then reset `mAmount` to zero. I would like to know the best way to do this. Thanks, greatly appreciated.

Comment: *warning: equality comparison result unused. note: use '=' to turn this equality comparison into an assignment*. The compiler sure is helpful.

Comment: What is Top() supposed to do (i.e. what is the top)?  and brainoverflow is correct of an expression problem.

Comment: Always compile your programs with high warning levels. You will be surprised how good hints can a compiler give.

Comment: ok ive just changed equality. yes a very silly mistake i didnt notice. i just want to know how im supposed to implement the top() function in main. i dont know how to go about doing it.

Comment: Note that you can avoid managing memory for the `CCounter` instance by allocating your `CCounter` on the stack: `CCounter myCount; myCount.Set(6); myCount.Increment(); ...` and omit the `delete`.

Answer (score 2):

Since I am not allowed to comment, an answer instead.

```
mAmount == 0;
```

should be

```
mAmount = 0;
```

To make it more of a real answer, the first line is like writing only `true;` in your code.